# java ensure completion of a thread without interruption

Tags: java, concurrency

I have many threads running, but I want to execute a particular thread (a TimerTask's run() method) to run to its completion and I don't want any interruption by any other threads.

I think synchronized(this) { } wont ensure its completion.

Please suggest me a correct way to do this.

Comment: This is a bit too general. Are there many Threads? Can you post some more details, and maybe some code?

Comment: Maybe this would help, [Guarded Block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)

Comment: If you run without locks, blocking and minimise you GC, it should run to completion without interruption. It may not run correctly which is usually more important, but that depends on your requirements.

Comment: When you say "interruption", do you mean programmatic interruption (ie `Thread.interrupt()`/`Object.notify()`, or do you mean the scheduler context-switching and letting other threads run?

Comment: What OS - are you running on a real time OS with scheduling  guarantees?  If not, you may well be in trouble...  Why do you need this?

Comment: @MartinJames with Windows xp. Actually one critical thread which I want to run to its completion does not do so, logs suggest other threads are getting their time-slices and the critical does not continue afterwards. Repetitive runs suggest that the critical thread stops in different point of execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch `InterruptedException` and set `interrupt` status once your work is completed.

[**Noncancelable tasks**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html)

> Some tasks simply refuse to be interrupted, making them noncancelable. However, even noncancelable tasks should attempt to preserve the interrupted status in case code higher up on the call stack wants to act on the interruption after the noncancelable task completes. Listing 6 shows a method that waits on a blocking queue until an item is available, regardless of whether it is interrupted. To be a good citizen, it restores the interrupted status in a finally block after it is finished, so as not to deprive callers of the interruption request. (It can't restore the interrupted status earlier, as it would cause an infinite loop -- BlockingQueue.take() could poll the interrupted status immediately on entry and throws InterruptedException if it finds the interrupted status set.)

```
public Task getNextTask(BlockingQueue<Task> queue) {
boolean interrupted = false;
try {
    while (true) {
        try {
            return queue.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            interrupted = true;
            // fall through and retry
        }
    }
} finally {
    if (interrupted)
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you can't prevent a Thread to be "interrupted" but this does not mean that the computation will be cancelled; just that any sleep/wait operations will throw an Exception. 
See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29).

If you don't want to exit then, you can [catch the InterruptedException and swallow it](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

> 'Actually one critical thread which I want to run to its completion
>   does not do so, logs suggest other threads are getting their
>   time-slices and the critical does not continue afterwards.'

This does not sound at all like an OS scheduling problem.  It sounds much more like the 'critical thread' is getting blocked or has exited because of some exception.

> Repetitive runs suggest that the critical thread stops in different
>   point of execution

- sounds more exceptionny than blocky.

If I'm wrong, and your critical thread is getting preempted because there are more ready threads than cores, you should raise the priority of your critical thread so that it does not get preempted, (or just reduce the loading on the box:).

The only other possibility is that your thread is using a huge amount of data and you're getting a lot of page-faults.  In this case, get more RAM, an SSD, or both!